# Contents table. How can I make it like the image?

Tags: table-of-contents, color, lists, chapters

How can I make a table contents table like this?

All I have is `\tableofcontents` and then what I have from my sections.[image]

Comment: There are two points where one can make changes.  Within \chapter, \section etc.there are commands like \addtocontents and \addcontentsline which write TOC info to the aux file.  This info is actually formatted using \l@chapter, \l@section etc.  You can use packages like titletoc to make these changes, but I find the titletoc interface more complicated then making changes directly to \l@chapter, etc.

Comment: Yeah but how can i sort them like this and add color, but still keep the ability to click on the chapters?

Comment: They don't need to be sorted.  You use xcolor to change colors and things like \large, |Large and \huge to change font sizes, and things like \textsf{...} to changee fonts.  The only tricky bit is suppressing the subsection number (\let\numberline=\@gobble).

Answer (score 1):

It would have been really helpful if you had provided an MWE showing what you had tried. As a GOM I am not impressed by someone simply saying "do this for me".

You can try the `tocloft` package, an example below that shows what might be done towards your plea.

```
% tocprob10.tex SE 535911 Change ToC look

\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{multicol}

\renewcommand{\cfttoctitlefont}{\hfil\Large\bfseries} % center the ToC title
\renewcommand{\cftaftertoctitle}{\hfill}

\renewcommand{\cftsecdotsep}{\cftnodots} % no dotted section leader
\renewcommand{\cftsubsecdotsep}{\cftnodots} % no dotted subsection leader

\renewcommand{\cftchapfont}{\scshape} % change look of chapters
\renewcommand{\cftsecfont}{\itshape}  % change look of sections

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\addtocontents{toc}{\begin{multicols}{2}} % two column ToC

\chapter{Chapter one}
\section{Section one}

\subsection{Subsection one}

\chapter{Chapter two}
\section{Section two}
\subsection{Subsection two}

\addtocontents{toc}{\end{multicols}} % end two column ToC
\end{document}
```

I am colourblind so don't deal with colouring text. You will have to deal with that yourself by appropriate redefinitions of `\cftchapfont` and `\cftsecfont` (and maybe other `tocloft` macros); read the manual `texdoc tocloft`.